# Dropping rows with duplicate indexes, based on criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on my masters project and ran into a situation where I could only come up with a rather slow and inelegant solution to. Thus, I reach out to you for suggestions as to how to improve this.

The core is an exploded pandas DataFrame (Let us call it `df` for ease) with a new column for the original indexes. This essentially looks as follows:

```
  originalIndex A   B
0       0       1   10
1       1       2   5
2       2       4   2
3       2       4   1
4       2       2   1
5       3       5   4
```

The goal is to drop all rows which have duplicates in `originalIndex` , except the one for which `abs(df['A'] - df['B'])` is smallest, ie, minimal. Thus, the new DataFrame ought to look like:

```
  originalIndex A   B
0       0       1   10
1       1       2   5
4       2       2   1
5       3       5   4
```

With the possibility of resetting the indexes (I'm familiar with that part).

My current method is as such

```
temp = df[df.originalIndex.duplicated(keep = False) == True]
for parInd in temp.originalIndex.unique():
    duplicate_df = temp[temp.originalIndex== parInd]
    duplicate_df["Diff"] = duplicate_df.apply(lambda x: abs(x.A - x.B), axis=1)
    minInd = duplicate_df["Diff"].argmin()
    test = duplicate_df.index.drop(duplicate_df.index[minInd])
    df.drop(test)
```

This takes ages for the large amount of duplicates a I have in one file alone, not to mention if I have to run it for more than one. Thus, I beseech you for something that improves on this ramshackle method.

Update: I've edited the example so that `df` is correct before and after.

Comment: Can you please elaborate "The goal is to drop all rows which have duplicates in originalIndex". I see multiple values of 2 in original index. How did you left with 2 4 1 row?

Comment: I'd like to drop all but one row, for which the value of original index are the same, so in this case 2 of 2, 3, and 4. I accidentally kept the largest value and will thus update the example to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your example should have row 2 with values `(3, 1)` for `originalIndex == 2` instead of `(4, 1)` as you show - because this in fact has the largest difference.  Your code would return `(3, 1)` and remove the other rows.

You should **always** avoid using `.apply` where possible.  There are many options for computing your function that are far faster, some of which include:

```py
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: abs(x.A - x.B), axis=1)
# 2.77 ms ± 250 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit abs(df.A - df.B)
# 226 µs ± 14.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit df.A.sub(df.B).abs()
# 193 µs ± 9.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit df["A"].sub(df["B"]).abs()
# 173 µs ± 3.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Secondly, you should change `df.drop(test)` to `df.drop(test, inplace=True)`, so that the drop is kept.  At the moment, your `df` is not actually changing.

You could simply use the following instead:

```py
# create difference column
df["diff"] = df["A"].sub(df["B"]).abs()
# sort by the difference, and drop duplicates in originalIndex
# (keeping the first, i.e. the row with the lowest absolute difference)
# sort by index again, so that in same order as before.
df = df.sort_values("diff", ascending=True).drop_duplicates(
    subset="originalIndex", keep="first").sort_index()
# drop the "diff" column
df.drop("diff", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: You're absolutely right in that 'df' is incorrect. Should be updated to something more appropriate now.
I've tested your solution (corrected to my names) and it ran in 2.9 seconds on first attempt and 3.8 seconds on the second attempt. That's much better than the over 40 min it ran for last time, not even getting halfway through all the data.
Thank you so much for the suggestions.